# How To Continuously Add lists to another in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know how to add arrays to each other in python but I am confused on how to continuously extend an array.

```
#import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlrd

path = r"C:\Users\berro\Documents\Sample Excel and CSV Files\shoesize.xls"

book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
#print(book.nsheets)
#print(book.sheet_names())

sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

print(sheet.row_values(1,2,4))


for x in range (1,11):
    trainX = [sheet.row_values(x,2,4)]
    trainX.extend([sheet.row_values(x+1,2,4)])

print(trainX)


trainX.append(sheet.row_values(2, 2, 4))
trainX.append(sheet.row_values(4,2,4))
trainX.append(sheet.row_values(5,2,4))
trainX.append(sheet.row_values(6,2,4))
trainX.append(sheet.row_values(7,2,4))
trainX.append(sheet.row_values(8,2,4))
trainX.append(sheet.row_values(9,2,4))
print(trainX)




#shoe size, height
features = [[sheet.row_values(1,2,4),sheet.row_values(2,2,4)]]
```

I'm some what new to Python, but I am having trouble finding an iterate-able way to extend the trainX array to my desired length.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range (1,11):
    trainX = [sheet.row_values(x,2,4)]
    trainX.extend([sheet.row_values(x+1,2,4)])
```

This overwrites `trainX` on every iteration, so in the end you will only have two elements in there. So you need to create the `trainX` outside of the loop, and then keep adding to it.

Note that you do not need to *extend* if you are just adding a single element on each iteration. You can keep the `append` then:

```
# create an empty list first
trainX = []

# start at index 1, end at index 9 (inclusive; or exclusive 10)
for x in range (1, 10):
    trainX.append(sheet.row_values(x, 2, 4))
```

Comment: Using list comprehenstion: **trainX = [sheet.row_values(x, 2, 4) for x in range(1, 10)]**

Comment: Thank you so so so much. This actually worked! I spent so long trying to figure out the problem only to be blinded by the obvious answer.